# Uncaught Exception error in Nodejs for get call

Tags: javascript, node.js, uncaught-exception

I am doing a JSON call using the request module in NodeJS but was getting

```
Error: Parse Error
    at Socket.socketOnData (http.js:1367:20)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:403:27)
```

and the process would exit without getting the response.
I put in a

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(e){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e, null, ' '))
})
```

and got this as the trace ..

```
Parse Error
{
 "bytesParsed": 238,
 "code": "HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT"
}
```

I tried putting in a try catch block around the get call but that did not work.
Once I started catching the 'uncaughtException' I got the stack trace and then the JSON response for the call. Please help me identify why this is happening and how I can efficiently handle it. I am using node v0.8.12

Comment: Could be your HTTP returned back from the server is invalid.  Can you connect with a socket (no http processor) or use something to see the raw http response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT means that either the server sent 'HTTP/1.0' at the wrong time or that the Content-Length header was wrong. Either way, it's a problem with the server and its response that will need to be fixed on the server side.

Comment: i am getting this error with IP cameras, when i do a request for snapshots. Does this mean the connection is bad?